# Multiple Update With Soft Delete Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Trying to implement soft delete with @SQLDelete annotation. Role(1) and Project Group (N) has One to many relation. I have to break relation when role is deleted. When I deleted role, role has a RECORD_STATUS set to D which is correct but, project group still has a relationship with role. We tried;

```
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE PROJECT_GROUP SET ROLE_OBJID = NULL where ROLE_OBJID = ?; " +
    "UPDATE PROJECT_GROUP SET RECORD_STATUS = 'D' where OBJID = ?")
```

but didn't worked.

Role Entity;

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Builder
@Table(name = "ROLE")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@DynamicUpdate
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE ROLE SET RECORD_STATUS = 'D' where OBJID = ?")
@Where(clause = "RECORD_STATUS = 'A'")
public class Role extends AuditableEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "UUID",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
)
@Column(name = "OBJID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private UUID id;

@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String name;

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable = false)
private String description;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "RECORD_STATUS", nullable = false)
@ColumnDefault("A")
private Status status = Status.A;

@ManyToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
        })
@JoinTable(name = "ROLE_AUTHORIZATION",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_OBJID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "AUTHORIZATION_OBJID")})
@Where(clause = "RECORD_STATUS = 'A'")
private Set<Authorization> authorizations = new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "role")
@Where(clause = "RECORD_STATUS = 'A'")
private Set<ProjectGroup> projectGroup = new HashSet<>();


public void addAuthorization(Authorization authorization) {
    if (this.authorizations == null) {
        this.authorizations = new HashSet<>();
    }
    this.authorizations.add(authorization);
}

public void removeAuthorizationByAuthorizationId(UUID authorizationId) {
    this.authorizations.stream().filter(auth -> auth.getId().equals(authorizationId)).findFirst().ifPresent(authorization -> this.authorizations.remove(authorization));
}
```

}

Project Group entity;

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Builder
@Table(name = "PROJECT_GROUP")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@DynamicUpdate
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, exclude = {"project"})
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE PROJECT_GROUP SET RECORD_STATUS = 'D' where OBJID = ?")
@Where(clause = "RECORD_STATUS = 'A'")
public class ProjectGroup extends AuditableEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "UUID",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
)
@Column(name = "OBJID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private UUID id;

@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String name;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
@JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_OBJID", referencedColumnName = "OBJID")
@Where(clause = "RECORD_STATUS = 'A'")
private Project project;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "RECORD_STATUS", nullable = false)
@ColumnDefault("A")
private Status status = Status.A;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_OBJID", referencedColumnName = "OBJID")
private Role role;

public void addProject(Project project) {
    this.project = project;
    project.setProjectGroup(this);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a `@PreRemove` listener in `Role` which sets the `role` of every associated `ProjectGroup` to null.